# How to make UIView global with button actions

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an application  with 10 different viewcontrollers in navigation controller. And i have UIView which i added subview to keyWindow of sharedApplication instance.

```
                 UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
                 UIView *myView = [UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,self.view.frame.size.width - 80,80,90)];

                [window addSubView:myView];


 UIButton *btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    btn1.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, prevVideoUIView.frame.size.height-
    [btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(button1Clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btn1.hidden = NO;
    [myView addSubview:btn1];

  UIButton *btn2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    btn2.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, prevVideoUIView.frame.size.height-
    [btn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(button2Clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btn2.hidden = NO;
    [myView addSubview:btn2];
```

I want the access of myView throughtOut the application wherever I navigate and on action user can put this view on screen at any point of time. The issue is suppose user navigates to third level of navigation controller and from there user added this "myView" on window as subview. and comes back to prrevious view then on touching the buttons on myView. app crashes saying bad access.

please do reply to this thread.

Regards,

parag

Comment: create a singleton class and add an object of `UIView` in it, instantiate the `UIView` in any of your `UIViewController`. And now using this class(singleton) use this `UIView` anywhere you want.

Comment: thanx vinay!! i m exactly looking for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you add your desired view in any of your view controller, when that view controller dismisses/pops, your view will also be released with that view controller. That is the reason of receiving *Bad Access Exception*.

You can create a class of type `UIView` and make that class *Singleton*. Once initialised, you can then add or remove your view from any of your view controller. By using *Singleton Pattern*, your view will be global and static.

You can also create your view in your `AppDelegate` class and by getting app delegate object in any of your view controller, you can add or remove your view.